# My constructor is only using default parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

So my code looks something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(string parameter = "bums")
    {
        //do various things
    }
}
```

And whenever I make a new instance of this class like this:

```
Base("poops")
```

It uses the default parameter ("bums" in this case) instead of whatever I put in and I'm panicking.

Comment: a) Calm down. No panic reason. b) Please a minimal compilable example.

Comment: [Any evidence for that claim?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97c7f9111c05962)

Comment: More efficient: `Base(const string& parameter = "x")`

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to show that program.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can delete "parameter" and write a constructor like this

```
class Base
{   string parameter;
 public:
    Base(string = "bums");
};
Base::Base(string a)
{parameter = a;}
```

or

```
class Base
{   string parameter;
 public:
    Base(string a = "bums")
    {parameter = a;};
};
```

Comment: why do you think this is the problem? You should also probably use a member initializer list, `Base(const string& a = "bums"): parameter(a) { }`